# How to find next "p" sibling of "this" element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, siblings

We know we can use following syntax to select next element.

```
$("div + p")
```

It selects  `<p>` element that are next to each `<div>` elements.
I want to select the next element using this.
for example
I tried

```
$("this + p") or
$(this + p")
```

But not working. Can anyone tell me correct syntax.

Comment: Try with .next() https://api.jquery.com/next/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select next sibling of element using [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/). Use it like bottom example:

```
$(this).next("p")
```